# draw a dot in the center of the screen psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox, experimental-design

I recently have started learning how to code in matlab, i.e. programming simple experience for cognitive psychological investigations. I wanted to ask, whether someone knows both, how to define, where to draw a dot in the screen,and how to define the fixation time before the stimulus onset. I know, that the code for defining a dot position is the following:

```
dotXpos = [?] * screenXpixels;
dotYpos = [?] * screenYpixels;
```

However, I don't know, which coordinates define the exact middle of the screen. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged as Android?

Answer (score 0):

In Psychtoolbox, most of the fundamental drawing routines are provided through the `Screen` function. To draw a dot, you can use the `DrawDots` subcommand:

```
Screen('DrawDots', windowPtr, xy [,size] [,color] [,center] [,dot_type]);
```

Here, the `xy` should be the position of all the "centers" of the dots. For you it should be `[dotXpos, dotYpos]`.

The center position of the screen is:

```
dotXpos = 0.5 * screenXpixels;
dotYpos = 0.5 * screenYpixels;
```

To implement a timed delay before stimulus appears, you can use `WaitSecs`

Please check out:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160515043421/http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/DrawDots
https://web.archive.org/web/20160419072932/http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/WaitSecs